Android: Robolectric test never finish, runs forever (MAC m2 apple silicon)
I'm trying to use Robolectric, however I can't make it work. No tests ever finish, even if I follow official docs & use a barebone, super simple example like this:
import org.junit.Assert.assertEquals
import org.junit.Test
import org.junit.runner.RunWith
import org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner

@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner::class)
class ExampleRobo {

    @Test
    fun someTest() {
        assertEquals(4, 2 + 2)
    }
}

If I run the test, it never finish, it looks like this - spinning forever...
My dev setup:

Mac OS (m2 apple silicon)
AS Hedgehog | 2023.1.1 Patch 2
Gradle 8.2 & AGP 8.2.1

This is my gradle testing setup:
// JUnit 4 & 5
testImplementation("junit:junit:4.13.2")
testImplementation("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter:5.8.1")

// JUnit vintage (so we can use simultaneously JUnit 4 & 5)
testImplementation("org.junit.vintage:junit-vintage-engine:5.8.1")

// external libraries (Mockk & Robolectric)
testImplementation("io.mockk:mockk:1.13.10")
testImplementation("org.robolectric:robolectric:4.12")

NOTE: I am aware of issues with JUnit5, so I am only using JUnit4 in my Robolectric tests - see imports. I am only using JUnit5 in my other classes tests.

You can run the test with a debugger, pause it, and see why it's stuck. Robolectric downloads the Android Framework first, so it's likely to be the download causing the issue. You can also enable logging like this:
android {
    testOptions {
        unitTests {
            all { test ->
                test.systemProperties["robolectric.logging.enabled"] = "true"
            }
        }
    }
}

The files are likely to be downloaded in ~/.m2/repository/org/robolectric/android-all-instrumented/.
You can also check it out to download the dependencies in advance.
https://robolectric.org/blog/2023/11/11/improving-android-all-downloading/
